# Show website from server2 keeping url from server1

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-masking

I have a **server1** (at **domain1.com**)

I have a website on a *server2* (at *domain2.com*)

I need to show contents from *server2* but showing **domain1.com** URL in address bar.

Is there a way to do it using .htaccess/mod_rewrite (or other solutions)  from **server1**?

Answer (score 0):

If [mod-proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html) is enabled on your server1 you can use the following code to rewrite requests from Server1 to server2 :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://server2.com/$1 [P]
```